# Facebook SDK conflicts with the android support 26.+ library

Tags: android, facebook, android-support-library

im trying to implement login with Facebook i followed the guide lines in here 
https://developers.facebook.com/docs/facebook-login/android 
but every time i get the following error

```
Error:Execution failed for task ':app:processDebugManifest'.
```

> Manifest merger failed : Attribute meta-data#android.support.VERSION@value value=(26.0.0-alpha1) from [com.android.support:appcompat-v7:26.0.0-alpha1] AndroidManifest.xml:27:9-38
>       is also present at [com.android.support:cardview-v7:25.3.1] AndroidManifest.xml:24:9-31 value=(25.3.1).
>       Suggestion: add 'tools:replace="android:value"' to  element at AndroidManifest.xml:25:5-27:41 to override.

and this is my Build.gradle dependencies

```
dependencies {
    compile fileTree(include: ['*.jar'], dir: 'libs')
    androidTestCompile('com.android.support.test.espresso:espresso-core:2.2.2', {
        exclude group: 'com.android.support', module: 'support-annotations'
    })
    compile 'com.android.support:appcompat-v7:26.+'
    compile 'com.android.support.constraint:constraint-layout:1.0.2'
    compile 'com.jakewharton:butterknife:8.7.0'
    compile 'com.android.support:design:26.+'
    compile 'de.hdodenhof:circleimageview:2.1.0'
    compile 'com.android.support:support-v4:26.+'
    testCompile 'junit:junit:4.12'
    annotationProcessor 'com.jakewharton:butterknife-compiler:8.7.0'
    compile 'com.squareup.retrofit2:retrofit:2.3.0'
    compile 'com.google.code.gson:gson:2.8.1'
    compile 'com.squareup.retrofit2:converter-gson:2.3.0'

    compile 'com.facebook.android:facebook-android-sdk:4.+'
}
```

i tried ass suggested to add `tools:value`

```
   <application
        android:allowBackup="true"
        android:icon="@mipmap/ic_launcher"
        android:label="@string/app_name"
        android:roundIcon="@mipmap/ic_launcher_round"
        android:supportsRtl="true"
        android:theme="@style/AppTheme"
        tools:replace="android:25.3.1">
```

What can i do to solve this conflict without downgrading my compile SDK to 25 ?

Comment: compile 'com.facebook.android:facebook-android-sdk:4.15.0' use this

Comment: as suggested can u use tools:replace="android:value"  in manifest and try?

Comment: @Raghavendra yup and it returns the following error
Error:Execution failed for task ':app:processDebugManifest'.
> Manifest merger failed with multiple errors, see logs

Answer (score 4):

You may not need this anymore, but someone may need it.

This fixed the problem for me:

```
apply plugin: 'com.android.application'

android {
    compileSdkVersion 26
    defaultConfig {
        applicationId "your.package"
        minSdkVersion 21
        targetSdkVersion 26
        versionCode 1
        versionName "1.0"
        testInstrumentationRunner "android.support.test.runner.AndroidJUnitRunner"
    }
    buildTypes {
        release {
            minifyEnabled false
            proguardFiles getDefaultProguardFile('proguard-android.txt'), 'proguard-rules.pro'
        }
    }
}

dependencies {
    implementation fileTree(dir: 'libs', include: ['*.jar'])
    implementation 'com.android.support:appcompat-v7:26.1.0'
    implementation 'com.android.support.constraint:constraint-layout:1.0.2'

    // FB compatibility. Consider removing them when upgrading FB SDK
    implementation 'com.android.support:support-v4:26.1.0'
    implementation 'com.android.support:cardview-v7:26.1.0'
    implementation 'com.android.support:customtabs:26.1.0'
    implementation 'com.android.support:support-annotations:26.1.0'
    implementation 'com.android.support:support-core-utils:26.1.0'
    implementation('com.facebook.android:facebook-android-sdk:4.28.0') {
        exclude group: 'com.android.support', module: 'support-v4'
        exclude group: 'com.android.support', module: 'appcompat-v7'
        exclude group: 'com.android.support', module: 'cardview-v7'
        exclude group: 'com.android.support', module: 'customtabs'
        exclude group: 'com.android.support', module: 'support-annotations'
        exclude group: 'com.android.support', module: 'support-core-utils'
    }

    testImplementation 'junit:junit:4.12'
    androidTestImplementation 'com.android.support.test:runner:1.0.1'
    androidTestImplementation 'com.android.support.test.espresso:espresso-core:3.0.1'
}
```

Comment: Thanks, this helped me

Comment: Can anyone explain, why we need to do this? - Thanks for help

Comment: It was needed because FB SDK was using an old version of support SDK.